# LibGDX's HTML project doesn't show anything in Browser

Tags: java, libgdx, webgl

The question is self explanatory, when I run my demo-html project as a Web Application and I open Chrome with the provided link by eclipse, my browser doesn't show the image it is supposed to show in a new project.. However, the tab displays the correct title "Demo". Can somebody help me with this?

Eclipse after Running the project:

[image]

And Chrome running the project:

[image]

I'm using the old setup-tool from Libgdx, the non-gradle way..

Comment: Stupid question: Is Javascript enabled in your browser?

Comment: yes it is @Springrbua

Comment: I've had luck with exclusively using the Gradle command `html:dist` to build the HTML project.  After building, you just need to host the dist folder on a web server. See here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#packaging-for-the-web

Comment: @bazola, thanks, but I've generated this project with the old setup-tool from libgdx, which is non-gradle. However, I know how to run the project with a web server this way too, but it would be (a lot) easier for me to just run the project directly from eclipse, right? :/

Comment: Are you using a web server (such as Apache Tomcat) because I don't believe (at least with the gradle setup) the output for HTML is runnable locally without Apache Tomcat or something similar.